# Exclude referral in GA doesn't work

Tags: filter, google-analytics

I've added a filter in Google Analytics to exclude traffic from our internal service, which shows in source as "localhost:4444".  {Custom filter, Exclude, Filter field = Referral, Filter Pattern = localhost:4444, Case sensitive = No}

However, when I view Traffic Source -> Referrals, localhost:4444 is still showing up as 1 of the source. I thought it should be excluded.

Is this a bug from GA? or did I do something wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Seems that is traffic from Selenium grid, we also noticed it in our reports.
But no one answer below works. Probably need to set refferral exclusion in the property settings -> tracking info

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem.  Here's what you need to do:

- Google Analytics Admin > Filters
- New filter
- Call it "Exclude Localhost" or whatever you want
- Filter type > Custom
- Filter field > Campaign source (I know, this doesn't really make sense)
- Filter pattern > localhost*  (don't forget the asterisk - this will filter out all localhost traffic)
- Verify the filter - if you had any traffic to speak of, it will show up here.
- Save

All done! You are good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Profile filters will only affect data going forward, not existing data.  If you're trying to filter existing data, make an advanced segment to exclude "Source" containing localhost:4444.

You can also try adding regular expressions to your filter to widen your net and hopefully catch the source.  Try changing Filter Pattern to `.*localhost:4444.*` instead.